# React Native - Map Data from JSON can be displayed as text but not map marker coordinates

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I've been able to pull map data from a local JSON file, and display as text on my app. However I am unable to use this data to position markers on my map.

The line of code I'm having trouble with is:

```
{this.state.data.map((dynamicData,i) => <Marker coordinate={{latitude:{dynamicData.Latitude}, longitude:{dynamicData.Longitude}}}></Marker>)}
```

Below is the code which includes the text line which when not commented out outputs the latitude and longitude data correctly as text:

```
class MapScreen extends Component {
        constructor()
        {super();this.state={data: mapData}}
        render()
        {
                return(
                        <MapView 
                                style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
                                showsUserLocation={true}
                                customMapStyle={mapStyle}
                                provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                                initialRegion={{
                                        latitude: 48.859402329205615,
                                        longitude: 2.350319507571479,
                                        latitudeDelta: 0.012,
                                        longitudeDelta: 0.012,
                                        }}>
                                {/* {this.state.data.map((dynamicData,i) => <Text>{dynamicData.Latitude}{dynamicData.Longitude}</Text>)} */}
                                {this.state.data.map((dynamicData,i) => <Marker coordinate={{latitude:{dynamicData.Latitude}, longitude:{dynamicData.Longitude}}}></Marker>)}
                        </MapView>
                )
        }
}
export default MapScreen;
```

I believe in theory this method should work however tried everything to no avail, returning the error:

> Unexpected token, Expected ","
> Referring to line the problem line. I can't however find the error in that line after trying many different options.

For reference the JSON file is:

```
export var mapData = [
        {
          "siteName": "Louvre Museum",
          "Latitude": 48.86074344,
          "Longitude": 2.337659481,
          "Description": "Former historic palace housing huge art collection, from Roman sculptures to da Vinci's \"Mona Lisa.\""
        },
        {
          "siteName": "Arc de Triomphe",
          "Latitude": 48.87389506,
          "Longitude": 2.295039178,
          "Description": "Iconic triumphal arch built to commemorate Napoleon's victories, with an observation deck."
        },
        {
          "siteName": "Eiffel Tower",
          "Latitude": 48.85841765,
          "Longitude": 2.294465185,
          "Description": "Gustave Eiffel's iconic, wrought-iron 1889 tower, with steps and elevators to observation decks."
        }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

the coordinate type shoud be

```js
  export interface LatLng {
    latitude: number; //float number not object
    longitude: number;//float number not object
  }
```

so remove `{}` from `{dynamicData.Latitude}` and `{dynamicData.Longitude}` to be

```js
 <Marker coordinate={{
     latitude:dynamicData.Latitude, 
     longitude:dynamicData.Longitude
}}></Marker>
```